# routes collection as?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, routes, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I implemented tagging to my site, based on this http://railscasts.com/episodes/382-tagging

I want to add the tags in my houses resources, so i get url's like this...

/houses/tag1
/houses/tag2
ect

My routes file:

```
localized(['en', 'nl', 'de']) do
  scope "/:locale" do
    resources :houses do
      collection do
        get ':tag', to: 'houses#index', as: :tag
      end
    #...
    end
  end
end
```

House controller

```
if params[:tag]
  @houses = House.tagged_with(params[:tag])
  @tag = Tag.find_by_name(params[:tag])
else
  @houses = House.find.all
end
```

House model (part)

```
def self.tagged_with(name)
       Tag.find_by_name!(name).houses
     end

      def self.tag_counts
        Tag.select("tags.*, count(taggings.tag_id) as count").
          joins(:taggings).group("taggings.tag_id")
      end

      def tag_list
        tags.map(&:name).join(", ")
      end

      def tag_list=(names)
        self.tags = names.split(",").map do |n|
          Tag.where(name: n.strip).first_or_create!
        end
      end
```

This works fine for the tags in the houses resources. But when i go to a house id (show method) by example houses/housename1 i get a error message

```
undefined method `houses' for nil:NilClass
house.rb:41:in `tagged_with'
```

What am i doing wrong?

Ciao..remco

Comment: Soo, can we see line 41 of `house.rb` *(as well as the context it appears within)*?

Comment: just update question line 41 is Tag.find_by_name!(name).houses

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The routes for houses and tags are collapsing. You need to decide how you're going to access tags. I suggest either:

**Option 1**

Tag could be a separate resource:

```
resources :houses
resources :tags
```

**Option 2**

The tag could be like a filter to `houses#index`. In this case you don't need to define the tags in the routes, just:

```
resources :houses
```

Then just use this kind of routes to filter houses by tags:

```
/houses/?tag=tag1
```